# Automapper DateType convertion exception on new server

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datetime, automapper

I have a asp rest api which runs fine on our old server and test systems as well in VS. But when i try to access apis (not all) i get an Date Time mapping exception. For me the old server and the new server are setup equal as well the database and the data only the old server is windows server 2012 and the new is window server 2022.

So I don't even know where to start looking because I can not reproduce the error on any other system.

```
AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Error mapping types.

Mapping types:
TTestingConfiguration -> TestingConfigurationDTO
Entities.TTestingConfiguration -> Models.TestingConfigurationDTO

Type Map configuration:
TTestingConfiguration -> TestingConfigurationDTO
Entities.TTestingConfiguration -> Models.TestingConfigurationDTO

Destination Member:
HexCreationDate

 ---> System.FormatException: 23.04.2020 13:27 is not a valid value for DateTime.
 ---> System.FormatException: String '23.04.2020 13:27' was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
   at System.DateTime.Parse(String s, IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.ComponentModel.DateTimeConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.ComponentModel.DateTimeConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)
   at System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.ConvertFrom(Object value)
   at AutoMapper.Mappers.TypeConverterMapper.Map[TSource,TDestination](TSource source)
   at lambda_method2000(Closure , Object , TestingConfigurationDTO , ResolutionContext )
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at lambda_method2000(Closure , Object , TestingConfigurationDTO , ResolutionContext )
```

Comment: DateTime conversions depend on a culture.  Generally a server runs in an 'invariant' culture, so datetimes are expected to be expressed in Iso8601 format.  Your date format doesn't follow that rule, therefore you get an exception.  Your client should send all date times are UTC in the format yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.fffZ.

Comment: Thanks. With the correct format it works. But now I get the root cause. The database column is set to "Text" instead to "DateTime". Happy converting ...